# Array.push(x,y,z) outputs flat array, but want nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, append

I want to use javascript(or jQuery) data structures to get the output in the form I'm expecting. How should I define the contents of my loop and which data structure should I use?

```
    var _uaArray = [];
         $.each(settings.hiddenElements, function(key, val){
           _uaArray.push($category, $action, $label, getValue($element));    
        });

console.log(_uaArray);
```

Actual Output:

```
 [User, Act1, Label1, value1,User2, Act2, Label2, value2, User3, Act3, Label3, value3]
```

Expected Output :

```
[[User, Act1, Label1, value1], [User2, Act2, Label2, value2], [User3, Act3, Label3, value3]]
```

Comment: Expected Output is not valid, { } denotes object with key:value pairs

Comment: updated, basically want an array of arrays?

Comment: Try to refine the title and tags to address the specific problem. It's naught to do with "data-structures" in general, or even an arbitrary transformation, but simply why the *given* transformation output (and the method used to generate it) is different than expected/desired ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enclose your array with [ ] like this :

```
var _uaArray = [];
$.each(settings.hiddenElements, function(key, val){
   // pushes one element, a new array of the four values, each loop
   _uaArray.push( [$category, $action, $label, getValue($element)] );    
});

console.log(_uaArray);
```